# Update specific row using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update specific row of table in codeigniter. But my code update all rows.

Model:

```
function edit_profile($array){
        $email=$array['email'];
        $this->db->select("email");
        $this->db->from("user");
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
        $this->db->update('user',$array);
            return 1;

        }else{
            return $query->num_rows(); 
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
     public function edit()
        {
        $name = $this->input->post('user_name', TRUE);
        $email=trim($this->session->userdata('email'));
        $array = array('user_name'=>$name,'email'=>$email);
        $result = $this->edit_profile_model->edit_profile($array);
        echo $result;
        }
```

And in new page it show the echo value 1.
How to update specific row? why `$query->num_rows()` return 1 and update all rows?

Comment: What are you trying to update? username or email?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using a `where` condition to update a specific record

```
$updateData = [
   'user_name' => $array['user_name'],
];
$this->db->where('email', $array['email']);
$this->db->update('user', $updateData);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    function edit_profile($username, $email){
    $this->db->set('username',$username);
    $this->db->where('email', $email);
    $this->db->update('user');
    $result =  $this->db->affected_rows(); 
    return $result
   }
```

Controller

```
  public function edit()
    {
    $name = $this->input->post('user_name', TRUE);
    $email=trim($this->session->userdata('email'));
    $result = $this->edit_profile_model->edit_profile($name,$email);
    echo $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model just use

```
$update_data = array('coulmn1_name'=>'value','coulmn2_name'=>'value');

$this->db->where('email', $email);
$this->db->update('my_table', $update_data);
```